# show(index) not working with IE8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Hey, I have been able to figure out what IE8 hates (show(index)), but not how to fix it. I know that what I need to do is having something.show(index), but I'm not sure what. Any tips would be awesome.

```
var index = 0;
var images = $("#gallery img");
var thumbs = $("#thumbs img");
var imgHeight = $(thumbs).attr("height");
$(thumbs).slice(0,3).clone().appendTo("#thumbs");
for (i=0; i<thumbs.length; i++)
{
    $(thumbs[i]).addClass("thumb-"+i);
    $(images[i]).addClass("image-"+i);
}

$("#next").click(sift);
show(index);
setInterval(sift, 8000);

function sift()
{
    if (index<(thumbs.length-1)){index+=1 ; }
    else {index=0}
    show (index);
}
```

Comment: What is "show()" supposed to be?  Are we talking about the jQuery method()?

Comment: Yes, it is a jquery method. This is the API page for show() http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need:

```
$(thumbs[index]).show();
```

but I'm not 100% sure because I don't know exactly what your code wants to do.

The opposite of ".show()" is ".hide()".  You can pass both of those methods arguments to tell them how long to take when showing the element.

Comment: hey Pointy, this is where the code needs to go (something.show()). However, it's not exactly right. Sorry for this short reply, I'm also playing around with my code and variations of your suggestions. I'm a newbie at jquery =) The code is used to display a slideshow and scroll through thumbnails (the slideshow fades to a new picture as the thumbnails slide).

Comment: The main problem is that this code works in firefox, chrome, but IE hates it.

Comment: It's very unlikely that it really does work in Firefox. There's no way to get to the jQuery "show()" method by just calling it like that, unless you've got other code that does something weird to arrange for that (in which case it would probably work in IE too).